# Function in onCreate not execute everytime

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[Android Studio] Any function in `onCreate` of `MainActivity.java` not executing/run everytime when we switch acivities.

When App open first time then function(for example Toast) in `onCreate` works. If we switch to `SecondActivity` and come again to `MainActivity` then function in `onCreate` not execute/run.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This Toast is example of my problem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

How can i execute my function everytime when `MainActivity` open?

Comment: Perhaps you should read the activity lifecycle https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#alc You should not be calling onCreate yourself

Comment: i am new in android so, please tell me which CallBack i use to execute my fun everytime.

Comment: Read the link i pasted

Comment: run your code on onResume method of Activity

Comment: @RustamSamandarov : Thanks dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for an event which fires on every state change to active mode then run your code on onResume method of Activity

As mentioned in above comment read about [lifecycle of Activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#alc)

Comment: Thanks Buddy, after put my  function in `onResume()` works  fine. [for noobie like me: for create `onResume` shortcut is, just press `Ctr+O` .